# How to iterate multiple times over data during PIG store function

Tags: apache-pig

I wonder if it possible to write a user-defined store function for PIG that iterates twice over the data / input tuples.

I read here http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Store+Functions how to write your own store function, e.g. by implementing your own  "getNext()" method. 
For my use case, however, it is necessary to see every tuple twice in the "getNext()" method, so I wonder whether there is a way to that, for example by reseting the reader somehow or by overwriting some other method...

Additional information: I am looking for a way to iterate from tuple 1 to tuple n and then again from 1 to n.

Does anyone has an idea how to do something like that?

Thanks!
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

This is from top of my head, but you could try something like this:

```
imports here ...;

class MyStorage extends PigStorage {

private int counter = 0;
private Tuple cachedTuple = null;

public Tuple getNext(){
    if (this.counter++ % 2 == 0) {
         this.cachedTuple = super.getNext();
    }
    return this.cachedTuple;
}
}
```

Comment: But that would me give the first occurence right after the second one. I was looking for an iteration from 1 to n and then again from 1 to n. Sorry for not making that clear enough. Thank you anyways.